# I am three chiefs

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, knowledge

I am the king beyond the wall.

I am three chiefs.  To many, a symbol of hope and peace.

And yet, I could adorn the banner of a coward.

What am I?

Hint #1:

> The king and the chiefs are not literal.  In fact, the first line could just as easily read, "In winter I am a conqueror".  I am just a nerdy-geek and couldn't resist adding a little nerdy-geek cultural reference.

Hint #2:

> "the banner of a coward" is almost literal, albeit stretching the meaning of the word "banner".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is

> White

I am the king beyond the wall.

> In Game of Thrones, almost the entirety of the land north of the wall is **white** with snow, frost, etc. Also, the mythical beings that occupy the land are known as whitewalkers.

I am three chiefs.

> Possibly in reference to the [three white chiefs of Lagos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welcome_to_Lagos)

To many, a symbol of hope and peace.

> White hope often refers to someone who is hoped to bring success to an organisation. 
>  A white dove is a symbol of peace.

And yet, I could adorn the banner of a coward.

> A white flag has been a symbol of surrender

Hint 1

> In winter, white conquers all other colours.

Comment: Well done on the answer and the explanations. :)

Comment: The three chiefs are actually 3 primes that when combined make up the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a silly answer . . .

> Mance Rayder from Game of Thrones

I am the king beyond the wall

> His most recent main title is literally King-Beyond-the-Wall. (Lateral Thinking = 0)

I am three chiefs

> He has three chief titles. King Beyond the Wall, The Unburnt King, and The King of Lies (last one given by Mellisandra in the show only I believe. Do correct me otherwise, I'm show only)

To many, a symbol of hope and peace

> He united the Wildling camps

And yet, I could adorn the banner of a coward

> He abandoned his post in the Night's Watch which is a treasonous and cowardly act

Realistically I don't think this is the answer but thought it was funny it seemed to match.

Comment: Have neither seen nor read, but I take your word for it. +1 for great match.

Comment: It's a little less nerdy of an answer.  I went with the nerdy first line because I couldn't resist but it could just have easily read "I am the king in winter".  Cool answer though.

Comment: Anyone who's ever seen Game of Thrones thinks Game of Thrones the ***second*** they read "king beyond the wall". @BrentHackers

Answer (score 3):

Is the answer

> A feather

I am the king beyond the wall

> Not sure but American Indian Chiefs would wear feathers in their hats to show they were chief or king.

I am three chiefs. To many, a symbol of hope and peace.

> In Christianity, feathers can represent virtues. 3 feathers symbolize charity, hope and faith. These are the 3 'chiefs', the many refers to the fact there are lots of Christians and the 'symbol of hope and peace' I have explained.

And yet, I could adorn the banner of a coward.

> In WWI if a man didn't go and fight in the war, he would be given a white feather to show he was a coward.

Comment: Good guess. Not what I'm looking for. think less literally with regards to 'chiefs'

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Jack Frost

The King beyond the wall

> King of the winter.

I am a three chief

> Chief of frost, snow and ice.

Yet I can adorn the banner of a coward

> As winter draws to an end, Jack Frost leaves like a coward and makes way for summer.

Comment: Getting closer but less winter-specific.